Displaying time in suitable format from database formating
I have query from database to calculate work hours in (time format HH:mm:ss), I get the result from query correctly , the query  :
SELECT ScdID, EmpID, CONCAT(EmpName, ' ',EmpLastName) AS EmpFullName, EmpCode,
    MIN(DATE(ScdEmpIN)) AS xDATEStart,
    MAX(DATE(ScdEmpOut)) AS xDATELast,
    SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(ScdEmpOut, ScdEmpIN)))) AS TOTAL
    FROM tblschedule
    INNER JOIN tblemp ON tblschedule.ScdEmpID = tblemp.EmpID
    GROUP BY ScdEmpID ORDER BY ScdEmpIN

the results what I want appears like this :

The results I want in red square shape but in datagrid is showing like this:


I noticed that if time is greater than 24 hours showed like first and second and 5th row(1 day and 5 hours and 45 min .....) and the other normally displayed..
My datagrid :

How can I resolve this problem to display time as total as database query format
I tried to format the datagrid cell like adding GridDateColumn and have no result as I want
also I tried to format the GridTextColumn (HH:mm:ss) also no result as I want ..
I am using visual studio 2022 c# syncfusion DataGridView
Is there way to resolve it
hope to hear from you
Regards ...
